# Emptying cache in wavesurfer

Tags: wavesurfer.js

Destroying the wavesurfer instance doesn't remove the cache used up. The documentation doesn't cover this. How can I remove the cache?

Answer (score 1):

If anyone wants to know I found out the answer.
You first have to destroy it = `this.wavesurfer.destroy();`
And then you have to clear it to remove the cache = `this.wavesurfer = null;`

It has to be done in this order.
As with all removal of cache, garbage collection can vary in terms of time, but expect the cache to be cleared within about 30 seconds or so.